# Comparing function to variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code which generates the error

Error in a == dplyr::mutate :
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

```
a <- dplyr::mutate
a == dplyr::mutate
```

How can I check that this is TRUE in R?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `identical()` function:

> The safe and reliable way to test two objects for being exactly equal. It returns TRUE in this case, FALSE in every other case.

With your example:

```
a <- dplyr::mutate
identical(a,dplyr::mutate)
# [1] TRUE
identical(a,dplyr::select)
# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to compare function body<sup>1</sup> if you insist on using `==`:

```
body(a) == body(dplyr::mutate)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The `body` function access and manipulates function `body` ([documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/body)).